# open new record after finish flow

Tags: visualforce, visual-workflow, class, pagereference

I created a visualforce page with an embedded flow. But If I click the "NEXT" button it appears the page https://domain.my.salesforce.com/Accountnull, but it should open the new account record.

How can I collect the record id?

```
*****PAGE*****

<apex:page Controller="Account_Redirect" lightningStylesheets="true" >
   <flow:interview name="account_create" interview="{!accFlow}" finishLocation="{!finishlocation}"/>
</apex:page>


***** CLASS *****

public class Account_Redirect {

  public Flow.Interview.account_create accFlow { get; set; }

public PageReference finishLocation {
    get {
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/Account' + newRecordId);
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
        }
}

public String newRecordId {
    get {
        String Temp = '';
            if(accFlow != null) {
            Temp = string.valueOf(accFlow.getVariableValue('AccountID'));
            }
        return Temp;
    }
        set { newRecordId = value; }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Important is that the new record ID, which is created by flow, is available for output.

**PAGE**

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Account" extensions="Account_Redirect2" lightningStylesheets="true" >
   <flow:interview interview="{!myflow}" name="account_create" finishLocation="{!finishlocation}"/>
</apex:page>
```

**CLASS**

```
public class Account_Redirect2 {

public Account_Redirect2 (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

}


public flow.interview.account_create myFlow {get;set;}

public Account_Redirect2() {
}

public String getendID() {
    
    if (myFlow !=null) 
        return myFlow.stored_new_recordid;
    else return 'home/home.jsp';
}
   
   public PageReference getFinishLocation() {
    PageReference endlocation = new PageReference('/' + getendID());
    return endlocation;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented that behaviour using a Lightning Web Component (navigateToRecord) within Flow, please take a look at [this pull request](https://github.com/trailheadapps/dreamhouse-lwc/pull/242/files#diff-04578ab37043e5f207bc2befc285741f253ef98bfdfca666edf57d091f6d9b8a).

Comment: Bear in mind I haven't tested the solution within a VF page, but I think it should work